# Revolution Slider is completely gray and not working. But works on other themes

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, css

The Wordpress Revolution Slider plugin is not working in my theme which is installed at http://www.alarpintl.co.uk/ . Please see the top grey area in the content box. That is where the slider is supposed to display.

I have set up all the slides. But it is just not working. The plugin developer told me to check this: http://pippinsplugins.com/never-remove-the-default-the_content-filters-in-themes/ but I am not sure what is to be done.

Can someone please check the website and let me know why the slider is not displaying? I used the shortcode properly and it is working on other websites... But what is wrong then?

Comment: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jQuery is not included in your page in the `<head>` prior to other scripts that require it. Move it above any other scripts.

Comment: But the website got so slow... why is that?

Comment: Depends what else is using jQuery. If there are many other animations, etc. that will slow the page. I don't see anything running slowly here.